# Is RFC 1514 still relevant?

Tags: monitoring, snmp, rfc

Is there any OS-agnostic standard these days better than [RFC 1514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1514)?

Comment: Is there more to this question?

Comment: RFC 1514 is obsoleted by RFC 2790.  That may be of interest to you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better in what way specifically?

[RFC 2790](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2790.html) obsoleted RFC 1514.

Answer (score 3):

No, it has been obsoleted by RFC 2790 (which is a draft standard).

For RFCs, [this](http://tools.ietf.org/html/) is my favorite site...